# Updating OpenCV CvNormalBayesClassifier

Tags: c++, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision, bayesian

I'm trying to use CvNormalBayesClassifier to train my program to learn skin pixel colors. I have a set of training images and response images. The response images are in black and white, skin regions are marked white. The following is my code,

```
CvNormalBayesClassifier classifier;
for (int i = 0; i < numFiles; i++) {

    string trainFile = "images/" + int2str(i) + ".jpg";
    string responseFile = "images/" + int2str(i) + "_mask.jpg";

    Mat trainData = imread(trainFile, 1);
    Mat responseData = imread(responseFile, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

    trainData = trainData.reshape(1, trainData.rows * trainData.cols);
    responseData = responseData.reshape(0, responseData.rows * responseData.cols);

    trainData.convertTo(trainData, CV_32FC1);
    responseData.convertTo(responseData, CV_32FC1);

    classifier.train(trainData, responseData, Mat(), Mat(), i != 0);
}
```

However, it is giving the following error,

`The function/feature is not implemented (In the current implementation the new training data must have absolutely the same set of class labels as used in the original training data) in CvNormalBayesClassifier::train`

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found that the problem was that the black and white images have been compressed and thus contain values ranging from 0-255. Therefore, there can be a new class label in the other images.

To solve this problem, use thresholding to make the value all become 0 or 255.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message states, you cannot 'update' the classifier in light of new class labels. The Normal Bayes Classifier learns a Mixture of Gaussians to represent the training data. If you suddenly start adding new labels this mixture model will cease to be correct and a new model must be learned from scratch.

Comment: but there are only two colors in the responses images, so I have only two classes right? how can there be a new class? Thanks.

Comment: @LiYinKong Sorry, I must have misunderstood your question. I thought you were aware there were different class labels and were attempting to 'update' the learned model.